# How to publish to another git after build using jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I have a private repo and want to publish the build artifacts to another public repo (it's the packaged application)

How can I do that in jenkins? I could only find publish on the git I've used to build.

Thanks

Comment: I see it  as the only option is to describe it in additional stage in your Jenkinsfile

Comment: are you using free style project? scripted pipeline or declarative pipeline?

Comment: @JRichardsz free style

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this:
- Using a shell script that calls the GIT command line tool.  This can be a post-build script, the same script compiling the code, etc.
- Same thing in groovy
- Call a downstream job to do that for you (probably the best solution IMHO)

The main problem would be the GIT credentials, but that is not an big issue...